# getting error while working with href in PHP

Tags: php

im using href to pass parameter from one page to other but getting error.
Notice: Undefined index: $table in /var/www/html/download/get_file.php on line 3
Error! Query failed:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 1' at line 3

what i want to pass table name in href to other script to executed it, so for that i have many tables.

hope this explain what i want.

```
 href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}&$table'>Download
```

here is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["dropdown"]))

{
$table = $_POST['dropdown'];
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata', 'balhaf');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = "SELECT id, name, mime, size, created FROM $table";
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
// Make sure there are some files in there
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
}
else {
    // Print the top of a table
    echo '<table border="1" align="center">
          <H2 align="center"> Report Table</H>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>

            </tr>';

    // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;' href='get_file.php?id=   {$row['id']}&$table'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }

    // Close table
    echo '</table>';
    }

    // Free the result
    $result->free();
    }
   else
   {
   echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
   echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
    }
  // Close the mysql connection
  $dbLink->close();

  }
  ?>
```

my second code 
get_file.php

```
<?php

$table =$_GET['$table'];

// Make sure an ID was passed
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

// Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
if($id <= 0) {
    die('The ID is invalid!');
}
else {
    // Connect to the database
    $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata', 'accounts');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Fetch the file information
    $query = "
        SELECT mime, name, size, data
        FROM $table
        WHERE id = {$id}";
    $result = $dbLink->query($query);

    if($result) {
        // Make sure the result is valid
        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        // Get the row
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            // Print headers
            header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
            header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);

            // Print data
            echo $row['data'];
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
         }

        // Free the mysqli resources
        @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
        echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
        }
        }
        else {
        echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: just a wild guess, but did you try this instead: `href="get_file.php?id={$row['id']}&$table">`. (notice the double quotation marks instead of single.)

Comment: @JPLew he can't use double quotations because he already did with his echo, but the problem here that he is not defining the variable name so the proper way would be `href='get_file.php?id=   {$row['id']}&table=$table'>Download`, beside of that he has a lot of threats in this code and he surely would be hacked but let's fix his issue

Comment: @ MaveRick no not working.

Comment: Man you have another issue besides of that you have  to  follow  @Mark Parnell instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes in href because single quote with variable inside is parsed literally as if there is no variable. Or just use {} as you have done with $row['id'].

On side note, huge risk!

Answer (score 1):

Update your link to `href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}&table=$table'` - that way you actually have a proper name/value pair in the querystring.

And then in the second file, use `$table =$_GET['table']`, not `$table =$_GET['$table']`.

As noted by others though, there are numerous security problems with your code. You need to rethink your approach to building the query significantly.

Answer (score 0):

problem is here..

```
$table =$_GET['$table'];
```

it should be

```
$table =$_GET['table'];
```

for this your this code : `href='get_file.php?id=   {$row['id']}&$table'>`

should be changed into this code : `href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}&table={$table}'>`

and your problem is solved..

**NOTE : mysql_* is depreciated now. So better use mysqli_* or PDO**